# NSView's mouseMoved is never be called

Tags: swift, macos, swift2, nsview

I find mouseDown is called but not mouseMoved. How can it get mouseMoved be called? Here is my code:

```
@available(OSX 10.10, *)
class MainView: NSView{
  override var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool { return true }

  override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect){
    titledString.draw(at:NSPoint(x:20,y:40))
  }
  override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent){
    //print("Mouse down")
    printMouseDown()
  }
  override func mouseMoved(with event: NSEvent){
    //print("Mouse down")
    super.mouseMoved(with:event)
    printMouseMove()
  }
}
```

what is it? how could i modify the codes

p.s. 
  here is the driver codes:

```
@available(OSX 10.10, *)
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
  let window = NSWindow()
  func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification){
    window.setContentSize(NSSize(width:200, height:160))
    window.styleMask = [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable]
    window.level = 1
    window.title = "Test"
    window.acceptsMouseMovedEvents = true
    window.contentView = MainView()
    window.center()
    window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(window)
  }
}

if #available(OSX 10.10, *){
  let app = NSApplication.shared()
  let appDelegate = AppDelegate()
  app.delegate = appDelegate
  app.run()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the delegate :

```
view.acceptsMouseMovedEvents = YES;
```

Comment: Dont understand. Could you say more?

Comment: MouseMouved event need his delegate enabled to work. So you have to put this line in the view's awakeFromNib, viewWillAppear or whatever else.

Comment: In latest swift: https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsview, it is depreciated